# Bash join csv files

Tags: bash, csv, join, paste

I've got three .csv files:

File1.csv

```
Header1
data1;data2;data3
```

File2.csv

```
Header2
data1;data2;data3
data1;data2;data3
```

File3.csv

```
Header3
data1;data2;data3
```

I want to join them like this:

```
Header1;     ;     ;Header2;     ;     ;Header3;     ;
data1  ;data2;data3;data1  ;data2;data3;data1  ;data2;data3
       ;     ;     ;data1  ;data2;data3;       ;     ;
```

I've been trying to join the files with `paste`, however the columns keep mixing up. I think this happens because sometimes one of the files has no data (only the header) or File2.csv has more data than File1.csv. In this case it should look like this:

```
Header1;     ;     ;Header2;     ;     ;Header3;     ;
       ;     ;     ;data1  ;data2;data3;data1  ;data2;data3
       ;     ;     ;data1  ;data2;data3;       ;     ;
```

Is `paste` the best way to accomplish this?

ps. I can change the way the .csv files are created. I'm now using semicolons as delimiter but this can be changed if it makes it easier.

Comment: I'd probably write something Perl/Python/Ruby. I think a simple command-line utility such as paste (or join?) won't handle your specific scenario

Comment: Are the number of columns fixed?, If they are not fixed, an empty file might always result in only one column. In the example given, you have three columns for an empty file (file only with header)

Comment: Yes, number of columns are fixed. I can change the header to be followed by two empty cells if that would help (eg. header;;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Python*** solution:

***merge_csv.py*** script:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f1, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f2, open(sys.argv[3], 'r') as f3:

    f1_lines, f2_lines, f3_lines = f1.read().splitlines(), f2.read().splitlines(), f3.read().splitlines()
    max_lines = max(len(i) for i in (f1_lines, f2_lines, f3_lines))
    fmt = '{:7s};' * 8 + '{:7s}'

    for i in range(max_lines):
        if i == 0:
            print(fmt.format(f1_lines[i],'','',f2_lines[i],'','',f3_lines[i],'',''))
        else:
            f1_args = f1_lines[i].split(';') if i < len(f1_lines) else ['', '', '']
            f2_args = f2_lines[i].split(';') if i < len(f2_lines) else ['', '', '']
            f3_args = f3_lines[i].split(';') if i < len(f3_lines) else ['', '', '']
            print(fmt.format(*(f1_args + f2_args + f3_args)))
```

*Usage*:

```
python merge_csv.py File1.csv File2.csv File3.csv
```

The output:

```
Header1;       ;       ;Header2;       ;       ;Header3;       ;       
data1  ;data2  ;data3  ;data1  ;data2  ;data3  ;data1  ;data2  ;data3  
       ;       ;       ;data1  ;data2  ;data3  ;       ;       ;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as described. Now I've changed the script to be able to handle more columns. Up to 7 columns works fine but when I try 8 columns it gives me an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_csv.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(fmt.format(*(f1_args + f2_args + f3_args)))
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: share your changes so I can see them (let's say via https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Matter, it seems that there occur some redundant values while splitting by `;`. I need to see the initial files. Besides, use my shortened version of `fmt`

Comment: Hmm, there was indeed something wrong with one file. I've now tried it again with some other files and it works now. Also with 8 columns. However, the shortened version of `fmt` doesn't seem to work. I'm only seeing two files being merged and also just partially. Your initial script works fine. I will do some more testing over the weekend. Thanks again.

Comment: @Matter, note, in case of 8-column file, it should be `fmt = '{:7s};' * 23 + '{:7s}'` (tested on Python 3.5)

Comment: Thanks, did some tests over the weekend and this works great. Also, it's fairly easy to change it to handle more documents.